# how to loop through an elements in jquery if the name attribute is an array?

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to loop through an elements if the name attribute is an array?

for example

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[test-1]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[test-2]" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[test-3]" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[test-4]" value="4" />
```

and then i will be able to get the array index

test-1
test-2
test-3
test-4

Help much appreciated!

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a css selector like so

```
$('input[name^="data"]').each(function(){
         //code
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/cqatyghb/

This is probably the best selector. Basically test that the selector starts with `data[test-` and ends with `]`

```
$('input[name^="data\\[test-"][name$="]"]').each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: this actually works but i have to combine @amit joki regex to make it work better.. thanks guys, you rock!

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape special characters with double backslash `\\` For now, you can do this

```
$('[name^="\\[data-"]').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("name").replace(/^\w+|[[]]/g,""));
});
```

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Answer (score 0):

This way You would use `$.each` :

```
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function(index, el) {
   console.log(index, el.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here' the actual implementation combining Carl and Amit's solutions

```
$("input[name^='data']").each(function(){
            name = $(this).attr("data").replace(/^\w+|[[]]/g,"");
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
});
```